# Soma de campos com separador de milhar em JavaScript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, soma

Estou fazendo o formulário de um processo em HTML/JavaScript a onde eu tenho um conjunto de campos que em um campo ele calcula a soma de 12 campos e em outro campo ele faz a porcentagem em relação ao outro. Antes de colocar as mascaras de separador de milhar, todos os cálculos funcionavam, assim que coloquei as mascaras o campo começou a somar somente somente os numero que se encontravam após o "**.**" e o campo de porcentagem começou a fazer o calculo errado.

Como posso fazer para que esse seja feita a soma e o calculo de porcentagem corretamentes sem que seja necessário remover a mascara? (Segue abaixo o código.)

```js
function VST()    {

                        var a6 = document.getElementById("med_6m_VS1").value;
                        var b6 = document.getElementById("med_6m_VS2").value;
                        var c6 = document.getElementById("med_6m_VS3").value;
                        var d6 = document.getElementById("med_6m_VS4").value;
                        var e6 = document.getElementById("med_6m_VS5").value;
                        var f6 = document.getElementById("med_6m_VS6").value;
                        var g6 = document.getElementById("med_6m_VS7").value;
                        var h6 = document.getElementById("med_6m_VS8").value;
                        var i6 = document.getElementById("med_6m_VS9").value;
                        var j6 = document.getElementById("med_6m_VS10").value;
                        var k6 = document.getElementById("med_6m_VS11").value;
                        var l6 = document.getElementById("med_6m_VS12").value;
                        var m6 = document.getElementById("med_6m_VS13").value;

                        $("#med_6m_VST").val(parseFloat(a6) + parseFloat(b6) + parseFloat(c6)
                                + parseFloat(d6) + parseFloat(e6)
                                + parseFloat(f6) + parseFloat(g6)
                                + parseFloat(h6) + parseFloat(i6)
                                + parseFloat(j6) + parseFloat(k6)
                                + parseFloat(l6) + parseFloat(m6));
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2">
   <label>Média Ultimos 6 Meses(m²):</label><span
    class="required text-danger"><strong>*</strong></span> <input
    type="text" class="form-control" id="med_6m_VS1"
    name="med_6m_VS1" value="0" mask="#000.000.000.000.000"
    onblur="VS1();VST();maskTabelasPaiFilho();">
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
   <label>Média Ultimos 6 Meses(m²):</label><span
    class="required text-danger"><strong>*</strong></span> <input
    type="text" class="form-control" id="med_6m_VS2"
    name="med_6m_VS2" value="0" mask="#000.000.000.000.000"
    onblur="VS2();VST();maskTabelasPaiFilho();">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema acrescentando um

```
 .replace(/[^0-9,]*/g, '').replace(',', '.')
```

na formula que resolveu o problema da soma.

O código em JS ficou assim.

```js
function VST() {

        var a6 = (document.getElementById("med_6m_VS1").value).replace(
                /[^0-9,]*/g, '').replace(',', '.');
        var b6 = (document.getElementById("med_6m_VS2").value).replace(
                /[^0-9,]*/g, '').replace(',', '.');
        var c6 = (document.getElementById("med_6m_VS3").value).replace(
                /[^0-9,]*/g, '').replace(',', '.');
        var d6 = (document.getElementById("med_6m_VS4").value).replace(
                /[^0-9,]*/g, '').replace(',', '.');
        var e6 = (document.getElementById("med_6m_VS5").value).replace(
                /[^0-9,]*/g, '').replace(',', '.');
        var f6 = (document.getElementById("med_6m_VS6").value).replace(
                /[^0-9,]*/g, '').replace(',', '.');
        var g6 = (document.getElementById("med_6m_VS7").value).replace(
                /[^0-9,]*/g, '').replace(',', '.');
        var h6 = (document.getElementById("med_6m_VS8").value).replace(
                /[^0-9,]*/g, '').replace(',', '.');
        var i6 = (document.getElementById("med_6m_VS9").value).replace(
                /[^0-9,]*/g, '').replace(',', '.');
        var j6 = (document.getElementById("med_6m_VS10").value).replace(
                /[^0-9,]*/g, '').replace(',', '.');
        var k6 = (document.getElementById("med_6m_VS11").value).replace(
                /[^0-9,]*/g, '').replace(',', '.');
        var l6 = (document.getElementById("med_6m_VS12").value).replace(
                /[^0-9,]*/g, '').replace(',', '.');
        var m6 = (document.getElementById("med_6m_VS13").value).replace(
                /[^0-9,]*/g, '').replace(',', '.');

        

        $("#med_6m_VST")
                .val(
                        (parseFloat(a6) + parseFloat(b6) + parseFloat(c6)
                                + parseFloat(d6) + parseFloat(e6)
                                + parseFloat(f6) + parseFloat(g6)
                                + parseFloat(h6) + parseFloat(i6)
                                + parseFloat(j6) + parseFloat(k6)
                                + parseFloat(l6) + parseFloat(m6)));
```